# Metrics are not getting removed from the bucket (Dalmatiner DB)

Tags: erlang, metrics, bucket, ttl

The metrics are not garbage collected from the bucket after the lifetime(TTL) in **Dalmatiner DB(DDB)**.

Configuration:
`lifetime: 60s`

Comment: Did you get any solution to this?